# Can I connect Apple Airpods to a Toshiba Portege laptop running Windows 8.1?

Tags: audio, microphone, skype, ear-phones, airpods

Apple's [Airpods](http://www.apple.com/au/airpods/) promise [seamless connectivity](https://9to5mac.com/guides/airpods/) to iPhones and Macs through intelligent sensors.

At work I use my existing Apple [Earpods](http://www.apple.com/au/shop/product/MD827FE/A/earpods-with-35mm-headphone-plug?fnode=cdef20b99bb9da80ae38a16c0e954268ff41aee4b094ca3bacc992517ec87cf4db0f848a787d936c4c85d9ae60b8873c4de0a13782f3c178412e2b58737f3d485258a28949752059212af9941391b654c37c749650608b0177264b859cb7cda92eb4346f99701dfff8b81be50f681b2f32fd71cfe5ebc2e3af3b9a02aa7c06cd) for [Skype business conference calls](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Start-a-Skype-for-Business-conference-call-8dc8ac52-91ac-4db9-8672-11551fdaf997) - as they provide a mic and earphones that are simpler and more compatible than [other USB based headgear](http://www.logitech.com/en-au/product/usb-headset-h340). (They integrate with the [earphone/mic combo jack port](http://www.pcnexus.net/2013/11/how-to-use-combo-audio-jack-on-laptops.html).)

Now I want to replace my Earpods (which are fantastic) with AirPods. Is this feasible?

My question is: **Can I connect Apple Airpods to a Toshiba Portege laptop running Windows 8.1?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Microsoft Skype for business does not support AirPods at this time (Jan 2018).  It's really strange. They will work with most other applications running in windows, but there is some conflict that Microsoft has not been able/unwilling to fix wherein the microphone will work, but there is no playback audio.

Answer (score 2):

I connect mine with various Windows devices.  On my desktop (Win 7 Pro) I put the airpods in discovery mode (push the button on the back until the white light flashes) and then go to Devices.  Select add a device and wait until the list populates.  Your airpods will be there.  Click on it and let the drivers load.